# Grunt + angular gettext: how to extract and/or compile continuously?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-angular-gettext

I am using grunt and grunt-angular-gettext with my angularJS project.
I would like to let grunt run grunt task `nggettext_extract` whenever a source file is updated, and `nggettext_compile` whenever a 'po' file is updated.
I thought I could just add the tasks names to my 'grunt.task.run' tasks list, this way:

```
...
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
  grunt.task.run([
    'nggettext_extract', <== added task, just executed on the first run
    'nggettext_compile', <== added task, just executed on the first run
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
  ]);
});
...
```

but unfortunately this works only for the first grunt run, and not afterwards...
It would even be acceptable for me to have both tasks run whenever *any* file changes in my project (I am not sure how to specify dependencies within Gruntfile.js, I'm quite new with it... :-().

If it can be of any help, these are my nggettext_ tasks configurations (quite standard):

```
   ...

   nggettext_extract: {
      pot: {
        files: {
          'po/template.pot': [ 'app/**/*.html', 'app/scripts/**/*.js' ]
        }
      }
    },

    nggettext_compile: {
      all: {
        files: {
          'app/scripts/translations.js': ['po/*.po']
        }
      }
    },

    ...
```

Comment: Please post the `watch:` section of your gruntfile. That's where you configure what runs when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something similar to this in your gruntfile should work:

```
 ...
 watch: {
  po-changed: {
    files: ["po/*.po"],
    tasks: ["nggettext_compile"],
  },
  update-pot: {
    files: ['app/**/*.html', 'app/scripts/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ["nggettext_extract"],
  },
 },
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I did already solved this issue myself, but your answer is correct. I did also add a supplementary task (`tasks: ['nggettext_extract', 'po_auto_translate' ]`) to `update-pot` watch, to run a script of mine to auto-translate missing entries, as an aid to human translators...